# TreeViewItem IsExpanded Binding Does Not Work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am attempting to bind the TreeViewItem's `IsExpanded` property to my ViewModel. I want to be able to be able to set the property to true and cause the TreeViewItem to expand. Alas, this does not seem to be working. Nothing happens when I click the button 'Expand All'.

I have tried binding it like so using TwoWay mode as well as trying to use a DataTrigger. I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. The debugger output shows I have no XAML binding failures during runtime.

Code behind:

```
namespace TreeViewProblem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }

        private void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("");
            //e.Handled = true;
            //TreeViewItem item = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
            //item.IsExpanded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewProblem"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        
        <TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="RegistryTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubKeys}">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding name}" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>

        <Button Margin="547,193,67,193" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" Content="Expand All">

        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

KeyViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace TreeViewProblem.ViewModels
{
    public class KeyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<KeyViewModel> SubKeys { get; } = new();

        public string name { get; }

        private bool _IsExpanded;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return _IsExpanded; }
            set
            {
                _IsExpanded = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsExpanded));
            }
        }

        public KeyViewModel(string keyName)
        {
            name = keyName;

            if (!name.Contains("test"))
                SubKeys.Add(new KeyViewModel("test"));
            else if (name == "test")
                SubKeys.Add(new KeyViewModel("test2"));
        }

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
namespace TreeViewProblem
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<KeyViewModel> Keys { get; set; } = new();

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Keys.Add(new KeyViewModel("Item1"));
            Keys.Add(new KeyViewModel("Item2"));
            Keys.Add(new KeyViewModel("Item3"));
            Keys.Add(new KeyViewModel("Item4"));
            Keys.Add(new KeyViewModel("Item5"));
        }

        public ICommand ButtonCommand
            => new RelayCommand(Expand);

        void Expand()
        {
            foreach(var key in Keys) 
            {
                key.IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that you put `TreeViewItem` inside `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. Replace it with e.g. `TextBlock` and bind `IsExpanded` in a style.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubKeys}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: How does my answer that I posted compare to yours? Which would you say is the better way?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working this way

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="RegistryTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubKeys}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding name}">
            </TreeViewItem>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```